# Div based web design tutorial/book

Tags: css, html

I want to try to use div tags and css instead of tables in my web design. Can you suggest any resource that I can learn using div tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a switch from tables to div's! Lot's of stuff to be learned.
Its smart to google and start reading about a few subjects before coding.
I think generators and grids are not what you are looking for, because you need to learn basic principles first.

Google for subjects like:

- css Box model
- css floats
- css positioning
- css resets

When u start with these subjects, the workings of the divs become a bit clearer. Then the real shizzle starts when you run into some inconsistencies with browsers and such (thats where the resets help).

Thats just my opinion. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are different css grid systems out there that can be a starting point for you:

- https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki/grids
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/
- http://960.gs/
- http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Comment: Those are for advanced level, he didn't ask about any CSS frameworks anyway :)

Comment: Not sure if they are for advanced users: the YUI grids system comes with a builder (the others too, I think), so he can have a decent cross-browser layout with little effort... but maybe you are right, as he said "learn" :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent tutorial on that:

[DIV web design](http://www.colorplexstudios.com/articles/div_web_design_tutorial/)

The key is to understand `float` and `clear` properties amongst other things.

Comment: @penguru: Then I can't surmise your understanding and what you consider detailed :)